# Is it necessary to explicitly define individual indices/keys on each column in a multi-column primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

If I have the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `Date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
  `RecordNum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`, `RecordNum`)
);
```

...do I have to set up an `index/key` on Date in order to optimize a query like `select RecordNum from MyTable where Date = ?` ?

Does the primary key combo automatically create two separate indices for each column in addition to the combination of them, or do I have to do that myself explicitly?

Comment: No you dont, try using `explain select ..` and see what you get.

Comment: Primary key is a unique index.  
Your create table will also create a unique index on the combination of Date and RecordNum columns. you don't need to add an index on date, but you might want to add an index in RecordNum, depending on the size of your table and the queries you use on it.

Comment: @Zohar Peled It's not clear to me what you're saying. Are you saying that the multi-column index does NOT create separate indices for each of the two columns, in addition to the index on both columns together? If you are, then that's contrary to what the accepted answer says in the duplicate question linked to (and the first comment).

Comment: This is what I'm saying, but it's not contrary to the answer you mentioned. What happens is you get an index in both columns, so there really is no need to create another index on the first column. a comment is too small to show you what I mean, so [take a look at this link](http://textuploader.com/xy02)